# Is there any way to generate one HTML report from two pytest runs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-html

my runtests.sh file contains the below scripts

- pytest -v -s <file_name_1> --html=report1.html
- pytest -v -s <file_name_2> --html=report2.html

I'm trying to obtain a single report file which should contain the execution report of both file_1 & file 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to run both files in the same run command, (as shown below), which will combine all results into the same report.

```sh
pytest -v -s file_1.py file_2.py --html=report.html
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. However, this executes the tests from two files in random. Is there way to run the tests by file after a file in an order?

Comment: You can use an existing pytest plugin such as https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/ to have the tests run in a specific order.

Comment: Did that answer your question? (On Stack Overflow you can mark answered questions as "Accepted".)

Comment: Yes. This answer resolved my issue. Thanks for helping.!